# Loop video with media fragments?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am trying to loop a video URL(with media fragments) when it gets paused. I set up a listener to call a loopVideo() function when the video gets paused:

```
function loopVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementById('Video1');
    var videoFile = 'file1.mp4#t=10,10'; 
        video.src = videoFile;
        video.play();       
};

document.getElementById('Video1').addEventListener('paused', loopVideo(), false);
```

So far the video fragment plays once, but doesn't loop when it pauses. Is there an error in my code or are media fragments the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is 2 years later but I'm going to post this because I just ran into this issue recently. Basically What I did was I dynamically got the values in the media fragments and then in my `timeupdate` video event listener checked whether the current time was greater than the upper bound of the media fragment. If it was greater than the upper bound, I set the current time to the lower bound and play the video. Here's the code I used:

```
function checkMediaFragmentBounds(video, x,y) {
   if(video.currentTime > y) {
      video.currentTime = x;
      video.play();
   }
}
```

And then here's a working JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irmoathlete/nubwfhsz/) where you can also see my logic for getting the bounds of the media fragment. Hope this helps someone else looking for this answer because that's how I found this was looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you hooked to the wrong event, should be `pause`

You can make an auto-loop video if you pass the fragment (in seconds) to the url and trigger "reload" after the fragment ends (and pauses) with `onpause="this.load()"`

```
<video autoplay onpause="this.load()">
  <source src="video.mp4#t=10,20" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```